# what locator can i use for span element with button tagname

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors

What locator can i use for the below:

```
<button class="buttonLeftEnabled  floatLeft" type="submit"><span>Continue</span></button>
```

Comment: Do you mean to ask - which locator to used to find the "Continue" Button?

Comment: Yes. That’s what I meant. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To locate the Continue button, you can use:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@type='submit']").click();
```

OR

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@contains(text(),'Continue')]").click();
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I have tried both but the problem is that it’s not actually clicking the button and the test is passing in my cucumber script.

Comment: Added click(); to the script. You can try now and hopefully it will click the continue button!

Comment: @user9790882 consider changing your test logic, it probably has some issue in a logic that it passed without completing the action it supposed to do.

Comment: I have tried to fail the test by using an if else statement, but it kept passing the cucumber step without clicking the bottom. Is there a way I can use JavaScript to handle this ?

Comment: @user9790882: If you're able to Find the Continue button, then can you please accept this answer. And for your another question regarding Javascript, please raise a new question.

Answer (score 0):

To locate the *button* with text as **Continue** you can use either of the following solutions:

- `cssSelector`:

  ```
  WebElement elem = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("button.buttonLeftEnabled.floatLeft>span")).click();
  ```
- `xpath`:

  ```
  WebElement elem = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@class='buttonLeftEnabled  floatLeft']/span[contains(.,'Continue')]")).click();
  ```